# How to debug - log4j message format is appearing instead of the message itself

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am running a `spark-submit` (version 3.2.1-amzn-0) job that executes Scala code (`RandomForest`) we've written on Amazon EMR 6.7.

```
spark-submit ...  --class ...RandomForest --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn ...
```

We are trying to debug some problems by using log4j v1 to print various bits of information.  Oddly, we do not see our log messages, but instead see what appears to be a log4j message format?!  Here's the relevant code:

```
object RandomForest extends Serializable {
    val logger: Logger = LogManager.getLogger("gov.afms.dbp.spark.analytics.RandomForest")
// ...
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("println before 1st log statement")
        logger.info("RandomForest start...")
        println("println before 2nd log statement")
        logger.fatal("RandomForest start (not really fatal)...")
        println("println says... RandomForest after log statements")
```

I collect the various logs from yarn using:

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_168...
```

Here's the odd output.  Note that the log4j messages themselves are not printed, but instead there's what appears to be a message format string - "%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n".

```
========================================================================================================
LogType:stdout
LogLastModifiedTime:Thu May 25 17:12:28 +0000 2023
LogLength:7256
LogContents:
println before 1st log statement
println before 2nd log statement
%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%nprintln says... RandomForest after log statements
```

It looks to me that there is probably a corrupt log configuration file somewhere, but where?  There are many possible places where a configuration file might reside.  Is there a clever way to find where?  If it's not a corrupt configuration file, what else might cause this behavior?

Update - I've searched through lots of log4j files and haven't found anything similar to the mysterious "%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n".
After looking around on the Internet, that string looks like a logback pattern, rather than a log4j pattern.  AFAIK, we weren't (consciously) using logback.  Perhaps it is leaking in from EMR somehow?

Comment: Ar startup, log4j print out the config it uses. Might have a look there.